# Translating function address to file offset

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

Let's say I have some code

```
_declspec(noinline) void foo() {
    printf("...");
}
```

And that I've mapped the executable into memory like this

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

_declspec(noinline) void foo() {
    printf("...");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* dos = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* nt = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)((UCHAR*)dos + dos->e_lfanew);
    return 0;
}
```

How do I translate &foo into an offset in the executable? Is this even possible?

EDIT: I tried @moonshadow's solution, but the address of the function is always outside the .text section, as seen below

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* getSection(const IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* nt_headers, unsigned section) {
    return reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER*>(
        (UCHAR*)nt_headers->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory +
        nt_headers->OptionalHeader.NumberOfRvaAndSizes*sizeof(IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY) +
        section*sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)
    );
}

_declspec(noinline) void foo() {
    printf("...");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(argv[0], GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    HANDLE hFileMapObj = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
    UCHAR* content = static_cast<UCHAR*>(MapViewOfFile(hFileMapObj, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0));

    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* dos = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)content;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* nt = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)((UCHAR*)dos + dos->e_lfanew);

    for(int i = 0; i < nt->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++) {
        auto sec = getSection(nt, i);
        printf("%s\n", sec->Name);
        DWORD va = sec->VirtualAddress + nt->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;
        printf("0x%x - 0x%x\n\n", va, va + sec->SizeOfRawData);
    }

    auto text = getSection(nt, 0);
    printf("%s\n0x%x\n", text->Name, (DWORD)foo);

    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Any of idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like an XY question. What are you ACTUALLY trying to do?

Comment: It's possible but it's awful. You'll need to walk the list of sections to find the one containing the address of foo, and use its offset in the original PE to perform a reverse relocation. There is almost certainly a better way to achieve whatever it is you're trying to do. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm not actually trying to do anything. This is just me being curious. Do you have any information on this technique @moonshadow?

Comment: When I build and run your example, I end up with .text at 0x401000 - 0x401a00, and DWORD(foo) yields 0x401198 - which is correctly in that range. What do you get?

Comment: When I run it I get .text at 0x401000 - 0x401a00 and (DWORD)foo at 0xf1000